# Having problems with simple Javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm having trouble validating my form. When the form is submitted i have  `onsubmit="return validateInput();"`. If the user Enters no data the function `validateInput()` works correctly, changing the HTML and displaying the messages I want. But I am also trying to call `function goodNum()` and `function checkCreditCard()`.

`function goodNum()` is ment to check that the phone number a user entered is correct, not just random numbers.

`function checkCreditCard()` serves the same purpose `goodNum()` but for a credit card.

The problem is that as long as the user enters any data into all the fields in the form it will submit. I am new to javascript and haven spent hours trying to work this out and am still clueless, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**JAVASCRIPT**

`

```
var validation = false;

function validateInput()
    {
        var valid = new Boolean(true);

        if(validation == false)
        {
            alert("Please choose the Pizza size to order");
            valid = false;
        }

        if(document.getElementById('customer_name').value == "")
        {
            alert("You must enter your name");
            document.getElementById('customer_name').style.background='red';
            valid = false;
        }

        if( document.getElementById('email').value == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter your E-mail");
            document.getElementById('email').style.background='red';
            valid = false;
        }

        if( document.getElementById('mobile_num').value == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter your phone number");
            document.getElementById('mobile_num').style.background='red';
            valid = false;
        } 
        else if(!goodNum()){
            alert("The number you entered is incorrect");
            document.getElementById('mobile_num').style.background='red';
            valid = false;
        }
        if( document.getElementById('credit_card').value == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter your credit card number");
            document.getElementById('credit_card').style.background='red';
            valid = false;
        }
        else if(!checkCreditCard())
        {
            alert("The credit card number you entered is incorrect");
            document.getElementById('credit_card').style.background='red';
            valid = false;
        }

        if( document.getElementById('customer_address').value == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter your Address");
            document.getElementById('customer_address').style.background='red';
            valid = false;
        }


        return valid;       
    }       
//checks the phone number the user entered
function goodNum()
{
    var num;
    num = document.forms["myForm"]["mobileNum"].value;
    var valid = new Boolean(true);

        if((num==null) || (num==" "))
        {
            valid= false;
        }

        if(num.length != 10)
        {
            valid = false;
        }

    var a = num.slice(2,3);

        if (!((a=="3") || (a=="5") || (a=="6") || (a=="7")))    
        {   
            valid=false;
        }
        for(index=3;index<10;index++)
        {
            a = num.slice(index,index+1);

            if((a< "0") || (a> "9"))
                valid =false;
        }

    var count = 0;
        for (n=0;n<9;n++)
        {
            a = num.slice(n,n+1);
            if((c == "0") || (c == "2") || (c == "4") || (c == "6") || (c == "8"))
                count = count+1;
        }

    var b = parseInt(mobilenum.slice(9,10), 10); 
        if (!(b == count))
        {
             valid=false; 
        }

    if(!valid)
    {
        alert("Re-enter your number.");
    }

    return valid;
}

//checking to make sure the user entered a correct credit card number 
//using the luhn formula
function checkCreditCard()
{

    var valid = new Boolean(true);
    var cardNum;
    cardNum = document.forms["myForm"]["creditCard"].value;
    var cNum = 0, checkNumber=0;
    if (cardNum.length != 16)
    { 
        valid=false;
    }
    for(var x = cardNum.length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        checkNumber = cardNum.charAt(x);
        checkNumber = parseInt(checkNumber, 10);

        if((x%2) == 0)
        {
            checkNumber = checkNumber*2;
                if(checkNumber > 9)
                {
                    checkNumber = checkNumber -9;
                }
        }
        cNum += checkNumber;

    }

    if(!(cNum%10)==0)
    {
        valid = false;
    }


    return valid;

}
```

**HTML**

```
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateInput();" id="customer_details"  method="get" action="http://atlantis.cit.ie/displayvalues.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Choose Your Pizza: </legend>
<table>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
        <img src="base.png" id="base" width="150" height="150" alt="base" />
        <img src="anchovies.png" id="anchovies" width="150" height="150" alt="anchovies" />
        <img src="cheese.png" id="cheese" width="150" height="150" alt="cheese" />
        <img src="onions.png" id="onions" width="150" height="150" alt="Pizza" />
        <img src="p4.png" id="pizh" width="150" height="150" alt="Pizza" />
        <img src="pepperoni.png" id="pepperoni"width="150" height="150" alt="Pepperoni" />
        <img src="olives.png" id="olives" width="150" height="150" alt="olives" />  
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="resize();validation=true;" name="pbase" value="small" /> Small</td>
        <td><input type="radio" id="radio2" onclick="resize();validation=true;" name="pbase" value="medium" /> Medium</td>
        <td><input type="radio" id="radio3" onclick="resize();validation=true;" name="pbase" value="large" /> Large</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Anchovies</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" id="Anchovies" name="anch" onclick="doVisible()"  value="0.50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Cheese</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" id="Cheese" name="ch" onclick="doVisible()"  value="0.50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Onions</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" id="Onions" name="oni" onclick="doVisible()"  value="0.50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Pepper</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" id="pepper" name="pe" onclick="doVisible()"  value="0.50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Pepperoni</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" id="Pepperoni" name="pep" onclick="doVisible()" value="0.50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Olives</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" id="Olive" name="ol" onclick="doVisible()"  value="0.50" /></td> 
    </tr>   
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Name:*</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="customer_name" name="customerName" size="35" placeholder="John Doe" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Email Address:*</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="email" name="emailAdd" size="35" placeholder="example@mycit.ie"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2"> Phone Number:*</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="mobile_num" name="mobileNum" size="35" placeholder="0851111111" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Credit Card Number:*</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="credit_card" name="creditCard" size="35" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">Address:*</td>
       <td><textarea id="customer_address"  name="address" rows="5" cols="27"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3"><input value="Order Now" onclick="" type="submit" /><input value="Reset Order" onclick="" type="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

`

(that isn't all the code, i have other functions that work so I don't think they are causing the problem, also, sorry for so much code)

Comment: Is this all the JavaScript code? There are some errors popping up in the debugger.

Comment: Try always using built-in debuggers from the browsers. For example Internet Explorer's 11+ Developer Tools (which are amazing), by pressing F12. There's also Firebug (an extension you can download) for both: Firefox and Chrome.  And there's the built-in from Firefox, Chrome and Opera (Ctrl + Shift + I).

Comment: Im pretty sure it is. Like i said im new to javascript, i may have gotten a few things mixed up with java, but im fairly confident that it is all javascript. Thanks for the advice, i didnt know about the  debuggers! ill go check that out now!

Comment: Sweet! I'd like to point out that there are many onclick functions like: doVisible() and resize() which aren't written. Those are giving errors. 

Also, try adding: event.preventDefault(); at the opening of the validateInput function.

Comment: One other comment. I see that your website is open to XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Please, see this: http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/

In English, the form that I'm having in my computer is being sent to your server and validated. If someone manipulates the form it can send it to your server and do some bad stuff in there!

Comment: i have doVisible() and resize(), its just they are working so i felt no need to include them. I will try adding that in. Thanks again for that tip about the debugging tools, its helping already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in the following code:

```
var count = 0;
    for (n=0;n<9;n++)
    {
        a = num.slice(n,n+1);
        if((c == "0") || (c == "2") || (c == "4") || (c == "6") || (c == "8"))
            count = count+1;
    }

var b = parseInt(mobilenum.slice(9,10), 10);
```

- `a`should be `c`
- `mobilenum` is not defined

When these two problems are corrected, your message "Re-enter your number" is displayed.

I have a suggestion as well. Since you are a beginner and this code is probably critical to the business you are working for, you should consider using a validation library. You can find a review at: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/the-ten-best-javascript-libraries-for-form-validation-and-formatting

Comment: Ya i just noticed the `a` ahould be `c` with debudding it thanks to @Jose A. Had not seen the mobilenum not defined yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I fixed thoes two problems and it works perfectly now, thank you so much. Hard to believe I missed them. And I'm currently in college, so not working for a business yet. But I will take a look at that, Thanks again.